# Instantiating a generic object that uses <Foo extends Bar<Foo>>

Tags: java, generics

I am working on creating a B+Tree class using generics. Here is the beginning of my class declaration and constructor:

```java
/**
 * B+ Tree generic type
 *
 * @author Sofian Benaissa
 */
public class BplusTree<K extends Comparable<K>,V>
    {

    private static int maxKeys = 10;
    private Node<K> root;
    private Node<K> currentLeaf;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public BplusTree()
    {  
        root = new Node<K>(null, 0);
        currentLeaf = root;
    }
```

I have created a gist with the complete source for this class here: https://gist.github.com/sfyn/7622365

Next I am trying to instantiate this class in another file. This line:

```java
private BplusTree<String><String>;
```

Followed by this line in a constructor:

```java
bptree = new BplusTree<String><String>();
```

Throws these errors when compiled:

```bsh
src/FileParser.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
        private BplusTree<String><String> bptree;
                                 ^
src/FileParser.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
        private BplusTree<String><String> bptree;
                                       ^
src/FileParser.java:30: error: <identifier> expected
        private BplusTree<String><String> bptree;
                                               ^
src/FileParser.java:39: error: '(' or '[' expected
                bptree = new BplusTree<String><String>();
                                              ^
src/FileParser.java:39: error: illegal start of expression
                bptree = new BplusTree<String><String>();
                                                       ^
5 errors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax

```
private BplusTree<String><String> bptree;
```

is incorrect.

The correct syntax is a comma separated list of type arguments

```
private BplusTree<String, String> bptree = new BplusTree<String, String>(); /* or new BplusTree<>(); in Java 7 */
```

Comment: Newbie mistake in Java, I bet.

Comment: @sfyn When you get a compilation error, it's often type mismatches or syntax errors.